# Expo get device local ip-address

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a mobile application using Expo framework(react native).

I need to find the device's local IP address in order to connect to a specific device on the intranet.

Please guide me through this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/network/#networkgetipaddressasync

```
await Network.getIpAddressAsync();
// "92.168.32.44
```

Comment: I tried this method but it gives the public IP of device. But what I need is local IP assigned to the device in local network

Comment: The iOS Simulator uses the host machine network so you should be able to just use localhost or your machines IP address, whichever IP your web service is listening on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Expo Network.getIpAddressAsync() which returns a Promise, so you need to resolve it first.

Here is an example:

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';

const ipAlert = async () => {
  const ip = await Network.getIpAddressAsync()
  alert(ip);
};

ipAlert();
```